# Display a confirmation message on template from backend(python/Django)

Tags: python, angularjs, django, twitter-bootstrap

Hi I have `JSONResponseMixin View`, the main function of this view is to change the status to confirmed once the user click confirms in the GUI. I want to display a pop-up stating that it's confirmed. How can I do that from the django views.py?

The following is my view

```
class ConfirmView(JSONResponseMixin, View):

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        status = 'error'
        msg = "this is from me"
        post_body = json.loads(self.request.body)
        fab_value = post_body['fab']
        mast_value = post_body['mast']
        comment = post_body.get('comment')

        try:
           object = Forecast.objects.get(fab=fab_value, mast=mast_value, type='XC')
        except ObjectDoesNotExist:
            object = []
        else:
            if object.status == 'notified(created)' or 'notified(updated)':
                object.status = 'confirmed'
                object.comment = second_po_comment
                object.confirm = self.request.user
                object.modified_by =User.objects.get(username=self.request.user.username)
                object.save()

        return self.render_json_response(dict(status=status, msg=msg))
```

Comment: You are already sending `status` and `message` to the client. What about just creating a modal window with simple html/css and show the message inside it?

Comment: Good point Alix, but can't create anymore html files inside my project.